# Efficiently check for adjacent accuracy (group membership?)

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, evaluation

I am doing evaluation on a machine-learning classification task with 6 levels: `A1, A2, B1, B2, C1 and C2`. These categories can be assumed to be ordinal, i.e. they can be ranked. As part of my evaluation, I want to measure how accurately my classifier classified texts within 1 of the 'actual' level. I refer to this as 'adjacent accuracy'. For example, if a text is actually ranked `B2`, then adjacently accurate results would be `B1`, `B2` and `C1`.

I have lots of data to go through, so I want to have a very efficient way to check for adjacent accuracy. I am included my best approach below (python3), but I am looking for any suggestions to squeeze more time out of it.

```
adjDict = {'A1':{'A1','A2'}, 'A2':{'A1','A2','B1'}, 'B1':{'A2','B1','B2'},
    'B2':{'B1','B2','C1'}, 'C1':{'B2','C1','C2'}, 'C2':{'C1','C2'}}

def isAdjacent ( actual, classifierOutput ) :
    return classifierOutput in adjDict[actual]
```

If necessary, the levels could be redefined to be numeric (1-6), if that could boost performance somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in` is not very fast, especially with `str`, you could use simple `int` and compare values:

```
A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2 = range(6)

def isAdjacent(actual, classifierOutput):
    return actual - 2 < classifierOutput < actual + 2
```

For instance, if you have a `A2` text, the actual value is `0`, so `isAdjacent` must return `True` if the `classifierOutput` is between `0 - 2 = -2` and `0 + 2 = 2`, so either `0` or `1`.