# How to get the adjacent accuracy scores for a multiclass classification problem in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to calculate the average percentage hit rate of the true class and the adjacent classes and implement it in my cross validation.

```
#Example of my classification problem (in total 9 classes)
y_true = [0, 0, 1, 5, 3, 4]
y_pred = [0, 1, 0, 8, 6, 5]
```

The regular accuracy would result in 16,67 (the first prediction is the only one that's true).
However, I would like to get the 'adjacent accuracy' which would be 66,67% in this case (the three first predictions are 'correct', together with the last one).

The formula would be like this: [adjacent accuracy formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6cg3.png)

where Pi stands for the total number of samples classified as class i, g is the total number of classes (= here 9), and n is the total number of samples.

I have already looked at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870194/efficiently-check-for-adjacent-accuracy-group-membership) but it isn't particularly helpful since I would like to incorporate this scoring measure into a cross_validate function.

This is my current code:

```
scoringX = {'acc': 'accuracy',
       'prec_macro': 'precision_macro',
       'rec_macro': 'recall_macro',
      'auc': 'roc_auc_ovr_weighted'}
cv_scores_rf = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=kcv, scoring = scoringX)
cv_predict_rf = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=kcv)
```

This is would I would ideally like to end up with

```
scoringX = {'acc': 'accuracy',
       'prec_macro': 'precision_macro',
       'rec_macro': 'recall_macro',
       'auc': 'roc_auc_ovr_weighted',
       'adjacent_auc': make_scorer(custom_adjacent_accuracy_score)}
cv_scores_rf = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=kcv, scoring = scoringX)
cv_predict_rf = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=kcv)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually wrote [a question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438340/in-ordinal-classification-how-can-adjacent-accuracy-be-expressed-mathematically) a few months ago on how to express adjacent accuracy mathematically, and after some thinking I [answered it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/439065/123277) with a formula that's a bit simpler than the one you gave. (You'll unfortunately have to follow the link to see it; Stack Overflow doesn't support math typesetting.)

This formula can be implemented fairly easily if we convert `y_true` and `y_pred` into numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 5, 3, 4])
y_pred = np.array([0, 1, 0, 8, 6, 5])

precise_accuracy = np.sum(y_pred == y_true) / len(y_pred)
adjacent_accuracy = np.sum(np.abs(y_pred - y_true) <= 1) / len(y_pred)
```

I included the simpler calculation for precise accuracy to help make the adjacent accuracy easier to understand by comparison:

- In the precise accuracy, we simply count the number of predictions that equal the true value and normalise by the number of predictions. `y_pred == y_true` is an array of `True` and `False`, and the summation simply counts the number of `True` values.
- In the adjacent accuracy, we instead count the number of predictions whose ‘class distance’ `np.abs(y_pred - y_true)` to the true value is no more than one.

I think the function you want can be implemented like this:

```
def custom_adjacent_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = np.array(y_true)
    y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
    return np.sum(np.abs(y_pred - y_true) <= 1) / len(y_pred)
```